# Angular Visual Studio code showing strange errors

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I'm sorry if the title isn't easily understandable at one glance. But I'm having very weird behaviour in my visual studio code. I'm seeing errors for very weird things like:

> [ts] Cannot find name 'constructor'

and many more. The errors started after I edited the code on another computer and pushed to git. On my main computer, I pulled from my git repo. The files came with many weird characters which i had to remove manually. All other files are working fine, but this specific file, `verify.component.ts` is showing weird behaviour. Someone help me please!! Thank you

[The reposiory](https://github.com/PuruVijay14/novelio)

[image: The image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need **`}`**

```
export class VerifyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('username')  username: MatInput;
} // remove this }
```

Comment: OMG I can't believe I did something so foolish. Thank you @Sajeetharan

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect syntax, please remove the **curly braces** and try.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

as Sajeetharan said,  and Also you are not implementing the `AfterViewInit`

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

  }
```

Comment: implementing ngAfterViewInit is not necessary.

Comment: I'm new to this so maybe it's a stupid question but if you're saying implements AfterViewInit, don't you need to implement it?

Comment: @CaseyR , I believe that he meant that the implementation is not causing the compilation error mentioned above, that’s true. However it’s a good practice to implement the interface if you are using it.